# Maven project running multiple times on the same machine

Tags: maven, maven-3

First of all, I must say that I am a noob when it comes to Maven, so I may write some terribly wrong things and I am sorry for that.

I have a Spring Boot (2.5.3) project made with Maven 3.6.1, with the following (inherited) project structure:

```
root (parent pom)
  +-- api
  +-- common
  +-- import
```

The `api` and the `import` modules have both a dependency on `common` module.

The `api` and `import` modules are, in fact, totally independent one to another. The common module has classes used by both modules.

The modules are run by cmd by using `mvn spring-boot:run` on each module (except common, of course) and are build with a `mvn clean install` in the project's folder.

Now to the problem. At some point, a requirement of independent builds of the two modules was made. This was decided because code changes in one module would require an unnecessary rebuild in the other project. Example: a rebuild of the `import` would mean also a rebuild of `api` which in turn would lead to an `api` service intrerruption.

To solve the issue, I proceeded to make two separate folders with the same project (pulled from Git) and then build (`mvn clean install`) and run (`mvn spring-boot:run`) each folder separateley.

So to be more clear what I do:

```
folder1
  "mvn clean install" at project root
  "mvn spring-boot:run" only for "api" module

folder2
  "mvn clean install" at project root
  "mvn spring-boot:run" only for "import" module
```

It seemed to work, but it's a false conclusion. Seemingly random, NoClassDefFoundError exceptions are thrown for classes that are in `common` module for one of the running module, but not for the other.

What I've noticed looking at logs, and I may have be very wrong, is that at some point the common module is packaged into a jar and copied into local Maven repository (~/.m2/repository). My uneducated guess is it that running `mvn clean install` two times in separate folders for the same project somehow make the common jar located in local repository unusable or slightly corrupted for the other project.

I am trying to understand what is happening and mostly why, because my assumption was that beeing separate folders, they shouldn't interact with each other, an assumption that turned out wrong.

What solution do I have to achieve independent builds for the project's modules? Also, the same NoClassDefFoundError exception occured when I've tried to run on the same machine the same project with different profiles.

A big thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't take advantage of a multi module build.. If your root correctly defines modules you could simply build from root with one go ... and automatically order the modules based on the inter dependencies...also why are you using old spring boot versions as well as old versions of Maven...

Comment: @khmarbaise Not really sure what you mean. Building in one go isn't a problem, in fact it's exactly the opposite is what I asked. The problem are the exceptions thrown when building and running separatley (in different folder) modules of the same project. What is the explanation for this behavior it's the thing I look for in order to understand and fix the issue. Also, what is the impact and how changes the problem the versions that are used for Maven and Spring Boot?